# middleman-deploy pushes from root instead of build dir

Tags: ruby, github, deployment, github-pages, middleman

#### Background

I'm using middleman-deploy to deploy to a github page for an organization.

It's my understanding that the middleman build dir (`/build` in this case) is what will get deployed to github. That is, the directory that contains files after a `bundle exec middleman build`, including the index.html file.

What I'm getting in my github repo is the root of the project. I'm using `bundle exec middleman deploy --build-before`

config.rb

`activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.method = :git
  deploy.remote   = 'https://github.com/FiercePunchStudios/fiercepunchstudios.github.io.git'
  deploy.branch   = 'master'
end`

#### Question

How do I deploy my middleman site to a github *organization* page, using middleman-deploy?

Comment: I also opened an issue on GitHub, and it seems several others are having the same issue. https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy/issues/114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robinbortlik, there's a handy little extension right on the github issue. https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy/issues/114#issuecomment-168139237

```
#lib/build_cleaner.rb

class BuildCleaner < Middleman::Extension

  def initialize(app, options_hash={}, &block)
    super
    FileUtils.rm_rf app.config[:build_dir]
  end

end

::Middleman::Extensions.register(:build_cleaner, BuildCleaner)
```

---

```
#config.rb

require_relative "./lib/build_cleaner"

configure :build do
  activate :build_cleaner
end
```

This deletes the build directory before the build action. Now you can just do a single command, like `bundle exec middleman deploy --build-before`

It's still not something I'd consider a fix, because I'd like to not have to add boilerplate to every middleman project I start. However, it's a convenient workaround that smooths out the deploy process for now.